# Text compare function eats up a lot of processing time c#

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have an object `CurrencyPair` which i have to compare for equalness in a loop.

The equals function is beeing called to filter out a specific duplicate from a List which I have not figured out how to optimize yet.
The calling function works like this:

```
while (true)
{
    CurrencyPair updatedPair = GetUpdatedPair(); // eg "btc-eth"
    CurrencyPair[] relatedPairsInWallet = GetRelatedPairs(updatedPair.BaseCurrency);
    // related pairs example: btc-usdt, btc-xch, btc-eth
    foreach(CurrencyPair relatedPair in relatedPairsInWallet)
    {
        if (updatedPair.Equals(relatedPair))
        {
            continue; // dont want to compare the pair against it self
        }
        /*
        ... compare pairs
        */
    }
}
```

`CurrencyPair.cs` with included `Equals()` function

```
/// <summary>
/// A curency pair is a set made of two currencies which can be traded against another
/// eg "BTC-USDT"
/// </summary>
public class CurrencyPair
{
    /// <summary>
    /// initialize CurrencyPair based on two currencies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="baseCurrency"></param>
    /// <param name="quoteCurrency"></param>
    public CurrencyPair(Currency baseCurrency, Currency quoteCurrency)
    {
        BaseCurrency = baseCurrency;
        QuoteCurrency = quoteCurrency;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The base currency which is to be bought/sold, eg XCH
    /// </summary>
    public Currency BaseCurrency
    {
        get
        {
            return _BaseCurrency;
        }
        set
        {
            _BaseCurrency = value;
            SetStrings();
        }
    }
    private Currency _BaseCurrency;
    /// <summary>
    /// The currency in which the base currency is quoted in.
    /// usually a larger or stablecoin such as BTC or USDT
    /// </summary>
    public Currency QuoteCurrency
    {
        get
        {
            return _QuoteCurrency;
        }
        set
        {
            _QuoteCurrency = value;
            SetStrings();
        }
    }
    private Currency _QuoteCurrency;
    /// <summary>
    /// eg XCH-USDT
    /// </summary>
    public string DashedString { get { return _DashedString; } }
    private string _DashedString = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// eg XCH_USDT
    /// </summary>
    public string UnderscoredString { get { return _UnderscoredString; } }
    private string _UnderscoredString;
    /// <summary>
    /// The fee which is payed for an outstanding limit order which resides in the orderbook of the exchange
    /// </summary>
    public double MakerFee { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the fee which is payed for an order which will be executed immediately
    /// </summary>
    public double TakerFee { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the minimum amount of quotes
    /// </summary>
    public double MinQuoteAmount { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the minimum amount of base currency to sell
    /// </summary>
    public double MinBaseAmount { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the smallest amount to be calculated with (eg 0.01 for USDT)
    /// </summary>
    public int Precision { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// set the strings to compare against other currencyPairs
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Strings are beeing used as comparison value because Different exchanges have their own CurrencyPairs.
    /// The strings though are interchangable
    /// </remarks>
    private void SetStrings()
    {
        
        if (_BaseCurrency == null || _QuoteCurrency == null) return;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_BaseCurrency.CurrencyString.Length + 1 + _QuoteCurrency.CurrencyString.Length);
        //char[] currencyStringCharArray = new char[_BaseCurrency.CurrencyString.Length+1+_QuoteCurrency.CurrencyString.Length];
        sb.Append(_BaseCurrency.CurrencyString);
        sb.Append('-');
        sb.Append(_QuoteCurrency.CurrencyString);
        _DashedString = sb.ToString();
        sb[_BaseCurrency.CurrencyString.Length] = '_';
        _UnderscoredString = sb.ToString();
        { }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// checks if two currencies eual each other. Per default, the exact order of baseCurrency and Quote Currency is not beeing checked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comparePair"></param>
    /// <param name="requireExactOrder">specifies, if switched base and quote currency still produce a match</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Equals(CurrencyPair comparePair, bool requireExactOrder = false)
    {
        return Equals(comparePair.BaseCurrency, comparePair.QuoteCurrency, requireExactOrder);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// checks if two currencies eual each other. Per default, the exact order of baseCurrency and Quote Currency is not beeing checked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Strings are beeing used as comparison value because Different exchanges have their own CurrencyPairs.
    /// The strings though are interchangable
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="comparePair"></param>
    /// <param name="requireExactOrder">specifies, if switched base and quote currency still produce a match</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Equals(Currency baseCurrency, Currency quoteCurrency, bool requireExactOrder = false)
    {
        if (requireExactOrder)
        {
            return this.BaseCurrency.Equals(baseCurrency) && this.QuoteCurrency.Equals(quoteCurrency);
        }
        bool firstCurrency = true;
        int compareIndex = 0;
        bool baseCurrencyContained = true;
        string baseCurrencyString = baseCurrency.CurrencyString;
        bool quoteCurrencyContained = true;
        string quoteCurrencyString = quoteCurrency.CurrencyString;
        // Dashed string equals currency1-currency2 (eg "BTC-USDT")
        // as opposed to UnderscoredString (eg "BTC_USDT" - different standard)
        foreach (char c in this._DashedString)
        {
            if (c == '-')
            {// currencyString = "BTC-USDT" - Find split char
             // switch first/second currency
                firstCurrency = false;
                compareIndex = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (firstCurrency)
            { // check if the first currency is mathich up
                if (baseCurrencyContained)
                { // this.BaseCurrency.Equals(baseCurrency)
                    if (compareIndex > baseCurrencyString.Length)
                    {
                        baseCurrencyContained = false;
                    }
                    else if (c != baseCurrencyString[compareIndex])
                    {
                        baseCurrencyContained = false;
                    }
                }
                if (quoteCurrencyContained)
                { // this.QuoteCurrency.Equals(quoteCurrency)
                    if (compareIndex > quoteCurrencyString.Length)
                    {
                        quoteCurrencyContained = false;
                    }
                    else if (c != quoteCurrencyString[compareIndex])
                    {
                        quoteCurrencyContained = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!baseCurrencyContained && !quoteCurrencyContained)
                { // neither input:baseCurrency nor input:quoteCurrency math this.BaseCurrency
                    // match no longer possible
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!baseCurrencyContained)
                { // input:baseCurrency did not match this.BaseCurrency. Maybe baseCurrency = this.QuoteCurrency?
                    if (compareIndex > baseCurrencyString.Length || c != baseCurrencyString[compareIndex])
                    {
                        // match no longer possible
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                if (!quoteCurrencyContained)
                {// input: qouteCurrency did not match this.BaseCurrency. Maybe baseCurrency = this.QuoteCurrency?
                    if (compareIndex > quoteCurrencyString.Length || c != quoteCurrencyString[compareIndex])
                    {
                        // match no longer possible
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            compareIndex++;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// check if a currency is equal to either quote or base currency of this
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lookupCurrency"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool ContainsCurrency(Currency lookupCurrency)
    {
        return this.BaseCurrency.Equals(lookupCurrency) || this.QuoteCurrency.Equals(lookupCurrency);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// pull data from a master pair in order to create a copy rather than reference
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="masterPair"></param>
    public void UpdateCurrencPairData(ref CurrencyPair masterPair)
    {
        this.BaseCurrency = masterPair.BaseCurrency;
        this.QuoteCurrency = masterPair.QuoteCurrency;
        this.TakerFee = masterPair.TakerFee;
        this.MakerFee = masterPair.MakerFee;
        this.MinBaseAmount = masterPair.MinBaseAmount;
        this.MinQuoteAmount = masterPair.MinQuoteAmount;
        this.Precision = masterPair.Precision;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dashed string format. eg BTC-USDT
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// this is the default format for Program internal caculations
    /// as oppesed to UnderscoredString used by some exchanges
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DashedString;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// inverted Dashed string format. eg USDT-BTC
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// some exchanges might list the pair in inverted format.
    /// Also used to calculate trades in opposing direction
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ToInvertedString()
    {
        return $"{_QuoteCurrency}-{_BaseCurrency}";
    }
}
```

Is there something that can be optimized or do I have to check how I can call `.Equals` less frequently?

Right now, the equalness function consumes >30% of the loop time which is a big issue for me.

Currency.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// a currency is basically a simple string value such as USDT or XCH
/// </summary>
public class Currency
{
    public Currency(string currencyString)
    {
        CurrencyString = currencyString;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Currency String eg XCH or USDT
    /// </summary>
    public string CurrencyString
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrencyString;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrencyString = value.ToUpper().Trim();
        }
    }
    private string _CurrencyString;
    /// <summary>
    /// The chain the coin is based upon
    /// </summary>
    public string Chain { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of currencies which are tradable against this currency
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, Currency> AvailableCurrencies = new Dictionary<string, Currency>();
    /// <summary>
    /// checks if the currency is the Same
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Equals(Currency currencyToCompare)
    {
        if (this.CurrencyString == currencyToCompare.CurrencyString)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public bool Equals(ref Currency currencyToCompare)
    {
        if (this.CurrencyString == currencyToCompare.CurrencyString)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Currency string, eg XCH or USDT
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CurrencyString;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to answer this without understanding more about the problem you are solving. What is the value of `this._DashedString`? That seems like a place to start. But if I were comparing currency types, I would probably convert the currency symbols to int/enum/struct so the comparison is fast. It is hard to answer how to do that without seeing the types that are being compared, though.

Comment: added th info to the code. dashed vs underscored is the way way, base and quote currency are separated in the final string (`"BTC-USDT"`) vs (`"BTC_USDT"`).
The enum suggestion is definitvely something I will look into. I need to generate enum on runtime though As I am pulling available currencies from apis.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the code for `Currency`? And the code that sets all of these values? It seems odd that you are not overriding `Equals()` on `Currency`. Also, why not just override `ToString()` of `CurrencyPair` to get your display string instead of comparing equality using a display string?

Comment: Sounds like you could just compare the strings like this `var dash = baseCurrency.IndexOf('-'); return baseCurrency.Length == quoteCurrency.Length && string.Compare(baseCurrency. 0, quoteCurrency, 0, dash) == 0 && string.Compare(baseCurrency, dash, quoteCurrency, dash, baseCurrency.Length)` But I agree that it seems like you should be parsing the strings when they come in so you don't need to do this

Comment: I have added both classes. @Charlieface thank you for the suggestion. I think I have an idea how to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good performance boost could be achieved by implementing an index.
For this, I added a cache for all available currencies:

```
public static class AllCurrencies
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> CurrencyIndexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private static int CurrentIndex = 0;
    private static object WriteLock = new object();
    public static int GetCurrencyIndex(Currency currency)
    {
        return GetCurrencyIndex(currency.CurrencyString);
    }
    public static int GetCurrencyIndex(string currencyString)
    {
        lock (WriteLock)
        {
            int result;
            if (CurrencyIndexes.TryGetValue(currencyString, out result))
            { // try to retrieve and return the currencyIndex
                return result;
            }
            // currency not in dictionary yet. Add it;
            result = CurrentIndex;
            CurrencyIndexes.Add(currencyString, result);
            CurrentIndex++;
            return result;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Currencies now pull the given currency index on creation:

```
public string CurrencyString
{
    get
    {
        return _CurrencyString;
    }
    set
    {
        _CurrencyString = value.ToUpper().Trim();
        _CurrencyIndex = AllCurrencies.GetCurrencyIndex(CurrencyString);
    }
}
private string _CurrencyString;
```

the `Equals()` functions could be rewritten to compare the int CurrencyIndex.
Currency:

```
public bool Equals(Currency currencyToCompare)
{
    if (this._CurrencyIndex == currencyToCompare.CurrencyIndex)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

CurrencyPair:

```
public bool Equals(Currency baseCurrency, Currency quoteCurrency, bool requireExactOrder = false)
{
    if (requireExactOrder)
    {
        if (this.BaseCurrency.Equals(baseCurrency) && this.QuoteCurrency.Equals(quoteCurrency))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else if ((this.BaseCurrency.Equals(baseCurrency) && this.QuoteCurrency.Equals(quoteCurrency))||
        (this.BaseCurrency.Equals(quoteCurrency) && this.QuoteCurrency.Equals(baseCurrency)))
        {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```